# what is wrong with my while and if construct

Tags: java

DESCRIPTION OF THE PROGRAM:
The program contain a list of Olympic years and where they took place. It is suppose to ask the user to enter a year and then give them the location.

My TASK:
I was asked to make the while loop and if construct inside so the if the user entered the wrong year of Olympic it tells the user Sorry, no Olympic Games were held in given_year.

MY PROBLEM:
the program prints the year if first Olympic regardless of the year given. What is wrong with my while loop? thanks

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.* ;

class  Olympics
{
   int     olympic_year  ;
   String  olympic_city ;
   String  olympic_country ;

   public Olympics( int given_olympic_year,  String given_olympic_city,  String given_olympic_country )
   {
      olympic_year    =  given_olympic_year ;
      olympic_city    =  given_olympic_city ;
      olympic_country =  given_olympic_country ;
   }

   public int get_year()
   {
      return  olympic_year ;
   }

   public void print_olympics_data()
   {
      System.out.print( "\n    In "  +  olympic_year  +
              ", Olympic Games were held in " +  olympic_city  +
              ", "  +  olympic_country  +  ".\n" ) ;
   }
}

class  OlympicsDataFinder
{
   public static void main( String[] not_in_use )
   {
      Olympics[]  olympics_table  =
      {
         new Olympics( 1896, "Athens",   "Greece" ),
         new Olympics( 1900, "Paris",    "France" ),
         new Olympics( 1904, "St. Louis", "U.S.A." ),
         new Olympics( 1906, "Athens",   "Greece"  ), 
         new Olympics( 1908, "London",   "Great Britain" ),
         new Olympics( 1912, "Stockholm","Sweden" ),
         new Olympics( 1920, "Antwerp",  "Belgium"   ),
         new Olympics( 1924, "Paris",    "France"    ),
         new Olympics( 1928, "Amsterdam","Netherlands"),
         new Olympics( 1932, "Los Angeles", "U.S.A."),
         new Olympics( 1936, "Berlin",  "Germany"   ),
         new Olympics( 1948, "London",  "Great Britain" ),
         new Olympics( 1952, "Helsinki","Finland"  ),
         new Olympics( 1956, "Melbourne","Australia" ),
         new Olympics( 1960, "Rome",     "Italy"   ),
         new Olympics( 1964, "Tokyo",    "Japan"   ),
         new Olympics( 1968, "Mexico City","Mexico" ),
         new Olympics( 1972, "Munich",   "West Germany" ),
         new Olympics( 1976, "Montreal", "Canada"  ),
         new Olympics( 1980, "Moscow",   "Soviet Union" ),
         new Olympics( 1984, "Los Angeles","U.S.A."),
         new Olympics( 1988, "Seoul",    "South Korea"),
         new Olympics( 1992, "Barcelona","Spain"   ),
         new Olympics( 1996, "Atlanta",  "U.S.A." ),
         new Olympics( 2000, "Sydney",   "Australia" ),
         new Olympics( 2004, "Athens",   "Greece"  ),
         new Olympics( 2008, "Beijing",  "China"   ),
         new Olympics( 2012, "London",   "Great Britain" ),

      } ;


      System.out.print("\n This program can tell where the Olympic "
                     + "\n Games were held in a given year. Give "
                     + "\n a year by using four digits: "  ) ;

      Scanner  keyboard  =  new Scanner( System.in ) ;
      int  given_year  =  keyboard.nextInt() ;

      int  olympics_index  =  0 ;

      boolean table_search_ready  =  false ;

      while ( table_search_ready  ==  false )
      {
         if ( olympics_index < olympics_table.length )
         {
            olympics_table[ olympics_index ].print_olympics_data() ;

            table_search_ready  =  true ;
         }
         else if ( olympics_index >= olympics_table.length )
         {
            System.out.print( "\n    Sorry, no Olympic Games were held in "
                           +  given_year  + ".\n" ) ;

            table_search_ready  =  false ;
         }
         else
         {
            olympics_index  ++  ;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the specific reason for your problem, but two things stand out: **1.** You're not using `given_year` anywhere, is that intentional? **2.** You can extract the whole index+bool+loop mess into a function with the signature `Olympics findOlympicByYear(int givenYear)` - you can use *extended `for`* and an early `return` instead of having to maintain an index and flag manually.

Comment: @millimoose this is most likely a school assignment to learn control structures, and I guess he was asked to specifically do that mess.

Comment: @millimoose is right I have to do it with a while loop and if construct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code...

```
public class OlympicsDataFinder {
   public static void main(String[] not_in_use) {
    Olympics[] olympics_table = {
        new Olympics(1896, "Athens", "Greece"),
        new Olympics(1900, "Paris", "France"),
        new Olympics(1904, "St. Louis", "U.S.A."),
        new Olympics(1906, "Athens", "Greece"),
        new Olympics(1908, "London", "Great Britain"),
        new Olympics(1912, "Stockholm", "Sweden"),
        new Olympics(1920, "Antwerp", "Belgium"),
        new Olympics(1924, "Paris", "France"),
        new Olympics(1928, "Amsterdam", "Netherlands"),
        new Olympics(1932, "Los Angeles", "U.S.A."),
        new Olympics(1936, "Berlin", "Germany"),
        new Olympics(1948, "London", "Great Britain"),
        new Olympics(1952, "Helsinki", "Finland"),
        new Olympics(1956, "Melbourne", "Australia"),
        new Olympics(1960, "Rome", "Italy"),
        new Olympics(1964, "Tokyo", "Japan"),
        new Olympics(1968, "Mexico City", "Mexico"),
        new Olympics(1972, "Munich", "West Germany"),
        new Olympics(1976, "Montreal", "Canada"),
        new Olympics(1980, "Moscow", "Soviet Union"),
        new Olympics(1984, "Los Angeles", "U.S.A."),
        new Olympics(1988, "Seoul", "South Korea"),
        new Olympics(1992, "Barcelona", "Spain"),
        new Olympics(1996, "Atlanta", "U.S.A."),
        new Olympics(2000, "Sydney", "Australia"),
        new Olympics(2004, "Athens", "Greece"),
        new Olympics(2008, "Beijing", "China"),
        new Olympics(2012, "London", "Great Britain"),};


    System.out.print("\n This program can tell where the Olympic "
            + "\n Games were held in a given year. Give "
            + "\n a year by using four digits: ");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int given_year = keyboard.nextInt();

    int olympics_index = 0;

    boolean foundrecord = false;

    while (true) {
        if (olympics_index >= olympics_table.length) {
            break;
        }
        if (olympics_table[olympics_index].get_year() == given_year) {
            olympics_table[ olympics_index].print_olympics_data();
            foundrecord=true;
            break;
        }
        olympics_index++;
    }

    if (!foundrecord) {
        System.out.print("\n Sorry, no Olympic Game was held in "
                + given_year + ".\n");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (olympics_index < olympics_table.length)` will always be `true` since `olympics_index` is equals to 0  at the beginning of your while loop.

You could simplify your program with a for loop :

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < olympics_table.length; i++){
    if(olympics_table[i].get_year() == given_year){
        olympics_table[i].print_olympics_data();
        found = true;
        break; //break the for loop because it has been founded so no need to iterate through the array
    }
}      
if(!found)
    System.out.print( "\n    Sorry, no Olympic Games were held in "+given_year+ ".\n" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are checking the while using the olympic_index and not using the given year that you have scanned for.  Try checking your while loop with given_year